# Write list of dict to CSV with custom delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dict, and i tried to write as CSV file with below code, it works.

**Sample Code:**

```
logKeys = logList[0].keys()
with open('/home/ec2-user/lascsvoutputfiles/'+inputFileName+'_'+'logdata.csv', 'wb') as logFile:
            w = csv.DictWriter(logFile, logKeys)
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerows(logList)
```

I tried to pass the delimiter as below, but it throws error.

```
w = csv.DictWriter(logFile, delimiter='~', logKeys)
```

**Error log:**

```
  File "LasioParser.py", line 44
    w = csv.DictWriter(logFile, delimiter='~', logKeys)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: What error? Please [edit] your question and include the error.

Comment: args and kwargs cannot be mixed

Comment: @LutzHorn: updated the question with error log, please have a look.

Comment: @chakri: What is that mean? i'm new to python.

Comment: use w = csv.DictWriter(logFile, logKeys, delimiter='~',)

Comment: @Aritesh: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pandas` for that, and if `L` is your list of dictionary you can simply build a dataframe with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

and then write back to `csv` with custom delimiter:

```
df.to_csv('your_file.csv', sep='~')
```